# EmEditorのOutputBarの画面サイズを適す表示領域と同等の50％くらいにサイズを拡大できますでしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
OutputBarのサイズは変更できますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

アウトプット バーのウィンドウ枠をマウスでドラッグすることにより、サイズを変更できます。

これをマクロで行いたい場合は、レジストリの `CustomBarWidth3` の値を変更してください。以下のサンプルの `cxHeight` の値を変更することにより任意の高さに設定できます。この例だとウィンドウの高さの半分になりますが、1行目をコメントにし2行目のコメント外せば 100 ピクセルに設定されます。

```
var cxHeight = Height / 2;   // ウィンドウの高さの半分に設定
//var cxHeight = 100;      // 100 ピクセルに設定
var bOrgVisible = OutputBar.Visible;
OutputBar.Visible = false;
editor.WriteProfileInt( eeRegCommon, "", "CustomBarWidth3", cxHeight );
if( bOrgVisible )  OutputBar.Visible = bOrgVisible;
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。マクロ設定で最初から出で来るOutputBarのサイズを設定することは可能でしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 残念ながらマクロではできないです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。機能追加のバージョンアップをお願いしたいです。処理によっては、出てくる結果の画面の方が確認する重要度が高いことがあります。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ピクセルなどで設定が難しければメインのテキスト画面との比率、パーセンテージ設定などを希望です。たとえば50と設定すると画面が半々になるなどです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マクロで設定する方法もあったので、回答に追加しておきます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。変化しました。このままいくと事項の処理もずうっと同じサイズになるので、    OutputBar.Visible = false;で、このOutputBarの画面を広くした処理を閉じるときに元の初期の高さに戻すには何と記述しますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マクロの最初で `cxOldHeight = editor.GetProfileInt( eeRegCommon, "", "CustomBarWidth3", 0 );` として、後で `cxOldHeight` を使って高さを元に戻すことができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。var cxHeight = Height / 2;   これでもともとの高さの半分にならずテキスト領域の100％以上の占有で表示されました。もともとの初期値の設定値(見た感じでは30％くらいに見えます)はどれくらいになりますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 既定値は 210 です。高DPIのモニターだと、この値が必ずしもピクセル値にはならないと思います。